# Oracle trigger not inserting values in another table

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have `SOAP_SERVICE` table in which if new value gets inserted into this table then the values should be insert into `SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS` table also. I am writing below trigger for this which does not have any error and compiled successfully. But when i tried to insert value into `SOAP_SERVICE` table then the value is not getting inserted into `SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS` table.

```
create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING.TRG_TRK_SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS
  AFTER INSERT 
 ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS (SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_ID,SOAP_SERVICE_ID,STATUS)
       VALUES (SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_SEQ.nextval,:new.SOAP_SERVICE_ID,'N');
END;
```

Comment: I think my trigger was correct the only issue was with the commit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, cannot reproduce this one:

```
SQL> CREATE USER RATOR_MONITORING IDENTIFIED BY "password"
2            DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;

User created.

SQL> CREATE USER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION IDENTIFIED BY "password"
2            DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT TO RATOR_MONITORING, RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLE TO RATOR_MONITORING, RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO RATOR_MONITORING;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO RATOR_MONITORING;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> ALTER USER RATOR_MONITORING QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;

User altered.

SQL> ALTER USER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;

User altered.

SQL> CONNECT RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION/password
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLE RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE (SOAP_SERVICE_ID INTEGER);

Table created.

SQL> CONNECT RATOR_MONITORING/password
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLE RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS
2              (SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_ID INTEGER, SOAP_SERVICE_ID INTEGER, STATUS CHAR(1));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_SEQ;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING.TRG_TRK_SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS
2       AFTER INSERT
3      ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE
4      FOR EACH ROW
5     BEGIN
6        INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS (SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_ID,SOAP_SERVICE_ID,STATUS)
7            VALUES (SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_SEQ.nextval,:new.SOAP_SERVICE_ID,'N');
8     END;
9     /

Trigger created.

SQL> CONNECT RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION/password
Connected.
SQL> INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE (SOAP_SERVICE_ID) VALUES (7);

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> CONNECT RATOR_MONITORING/password
Connected.
SQL> SELECT * FROM RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS;

SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS_ID SOAP_SERVICE_ID S
---------------------- --------------- -
                     1               7 N
```

Notes:

1. The `CREATE ANY TRIGGER` privilege is necessary for `RATOR_MONITORING` to create a trigger on a table in another schema,
2. When we change connection in SQL*Plus, the database creates a new session for us to use.  Changes made in one session are not visible in another session until these changes are committed.
3. SQL*Plus implicitly commits transactions when disconnecting.  In the above example, we commit explicitly before the last `CONNECT` so that we are not relying on implicit behaviour.

Comment: nice and complete example; I was a few minutes slower:); But I thing to fully demonstarte you should connect with the created user (and not use the SYS). The consequence is that the user RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION has not SELECT grant on RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS. A connect with RATOR_MONITORING (without commit) gives an empty table.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: that's a fair point, I've updated the script to connect as the relevant users along the way.

Comment: I think my trigger was correct the only issue was with the commit..I cannot provide commit in my trigger it will give an error. SO i have to explicitly use commit everytime right ?

Comment: @Rahul - this is a standard transaction logik. The session that inserts a record in the table with the trigger can select the data from *both* tables (provided it has SELECT priviledge). And the new records in **both** tables are invisible for other session untill you commit the transaction. How offen you commit depends on your application logic, e.g. if other session should see each new record, you must commit after each insert.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable explanation is that you select the table `RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS` with a different connection without COMMITing the original session performing the insert in `RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SOAP_SERVICE`.
After the commit the record should be visible.

Note also that this is a side-effect of the fact that the trigger is in a different schema than the table; the user RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION can insert in the table `RATOR_MONITORING.SOAP_SERVICE_STATUS` even if he/she doen't have INSERT grant!

To enable this the user  RATOR_MONITORING must have the privilege `create any trigger` - which is not always considered as best practice (as to mighty privilege) - see eg [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6386500346452721)